# In background script, browser.tabs.create opens the page but displays Error: No window matching {"matchesHost":["<all_urls>"]}

Tags: javascript, storage, firefox-addon-webextensions

My  usecase is pretty simple:

- Click a browserAction icon on toolbar
- Listen the click in background script
- Create a new tab with a page present in same directory as `manifest.json`
- The said page has javascript file associated in `<script>` element.

  Below is the structure of app and code

  [image]

**manifest.json**

```
{

  "description": "app",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "1.0",

 "permissions" : [
    "activeTab", "tabs", "<all_urls>","host"
 ],

"background" :{
   "scripts" : ["bg/background.js"]
},

"browser_action": {
   "default_icon": {
    "16": "icons/page-16.png",
    "32": "icons/page-32.png"
   }
 }
}
```

**background.js**

```
 console.log("Message from backgroundjs."); 
 browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener((id)=>{
    browser.tabs.create({
       url: browser.runtime.getURL("../tab/html/app.html")
    });
});
```

**app.html**

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>bookmarks</title>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"> -->
 </head>
 <body>
       <p>before script</p>
       <script src="../js/tabApp.js"></script>
      <p> after script </p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**tabApp.js**

```
     //a simple console message
    console.log("hello from the other end");
```

**Output**

```
- Message from backgroundjs.  background.js:8:2
- hello from the other end  tabApp.js:3:1
- Error: No window matching {"matchesHost":["<all_urls>"]}  (unknown)
```

> The output is expected except the `Error: No window matching {"matchesHost":["<all_urls>"]}`. I am not sure what causes this error.

I have done following things to debug till now

- added the  permission

Please give your inputs

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check what is the output of

```
console.log(browser.runtime.getURL("../tab/html/app.html")
```

It looks like relative path is not from the manifest.json (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/getURL)

Comment: so the url formed is:
moz-extension://e8e74721-13fd-4b0f-a638-1f5c104b3097/tab/html/app.html

The web extensions is running. I do not have any errors or code freeze. It is just that, I am curious what causes this. 
I tried to remove all the extensions to check if this is coming from some other extensions. But no. It happens only when I run the webextensions